# android mediaplayer doesn't update duration of video when streaming from remote server

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming, android-videoview

The streamed file is recording in a file on a server and the duration is increasing, but the mediaplayer gets the duration only once and the playback stops when this duration is reached.
mediaplayer gets the duration of the stream only when the source is set:

`mp.setDataSource("http://url/1.ts");`

The question is how to update the mediaplayer duration without stopping the video playback?

Comment: Are you storing somewhere and streaming or your are directly streaming it from camera??

Comment: it's not from camera, it is being recorded in a file on a server

Answer (score 1):

first: define Runnable method like this

```
private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void run() {
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        startTimeField.setText(String.format(
                "%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime)
                        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                .toMinutes((long) startTime))));
        float i = (float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        float ii = (float) mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        float iii = (i / ii) * 100;

        seekbar.setProgress((int) iii);
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);

    }
};
```

then call the Runnable method like this in thread (AsyncTask class)

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime, 100);
}); }
```

and this is the handler decleration if you need it:

```
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

dont forgot to remove the handler by posting this code:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    seekbar.setProgress(0);
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);                       
                    myHandler.removeCallbacks(UpdateSongTime);
                    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

                }
            });
```

hope this will help you :)

Comment: thanks but it's not the seekbar that i need to update, it is the actual duration of the video that should be retrieved from the file on the server